# How do I stop spore blossoms from creating particles everywhere?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to either stop spore blossoms from creating particles, or reduce the distance from the spore blossom that the particles can spawn.

Comment: I might be wrong, but can't you just turn off particles by going to video settings and setting Particles to Minimal? I assume spore blossoms is a mod, so if you have optifine you should go to video settings -> animations and then turn it off from there.

Comment: @ScythePhantom spore blossoms are blocks that generate in lush caves which is part of the 1.17 update, and OptiFine is not compatible with 1.17 yet so I cant do that.

Comment: I guess I should upgrade to 1.17 :). Is setting particles to minimum still enough?